# Linq to SQL - match list to another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table Companies. And another table CompanyTypes.

One company can have multiple types.

I want to search companies with a select list of types (loaded into a list of strings).

If Company had only one type, I would do as follows:

```
Where searchTypes.Contains(Company.Type)
```

But how I execute a more complex query to get companies with desired types in another table?

Comment: I think you might need to give a little more detail (even if you change names to mask confidential information).  Then the solution that will most likely come up is to use the join keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (where you get CompanyTypes and Companies from your data):

```
IEnumerable<string> companyTypes = data.CompanyTypes; // filter this as needed
IEnumerable<Company> companiesOfType = data.Companies.Where(c => c.Types.Any(t => companyTypes.Contains(t)));
```

This will get you all companies that have at least one of the filtered company types. If you want all companies that have *all* the filtered company types, you can do this instead:

```
IEnumerable<string> companyTypes = data.CompanyTypes; // filter this as needed
IEnumerable<Company> companiesOfType = data.Companies.Where(c => c.Types.All(t => companyTypes.Contains(t)));
```

Comment: Will the query provider be able to translate such a query?